# Using signtool.exe through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automation, digital-signature, signtool

I am using an EV Code Token USB for this process.

I've got this .bat which signs an .exe with the help of signtool.exe

The bat works fine when i call it locally from cmd. It first calls an [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script (that is looking for the Windows Security [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvTrY.png) that is triggered by the signtool.exe (where you have to enter the PIN in order to successfully sign the .exe), starts the signtool process, the pin is entered automatically and all's good.

I'm trying to call the same .bat with the help of Jenkins, but no matter what I do, I keep getting this error

Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147023892/0x800703ec)

SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.

The error means invalid flags but I literally do not know what that means.
The signing command line looks like this:

signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/?signature=sha2 /td SHA256 /sha1 [thumbprint] .exe

It doesn't change a thing if I run just the above command in Jenkins' "execute windows batch command" build step.

How could I get past this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing were you able to figure this out? If you're able to share any portion of your .bat that got the autohotkey to fill in the PIN that would be amazing as well! Happy to put a bounty on this question if you're still struggling like me :)